# How may I get hold of $\eqdot$?

Tags: symbols

I want access to an equality sign with a dot under it, as with eqdot in the stix package. But unfortunately I get an error with the message that there are too many packages loaded.

More precisely, the error message is: ``Too many symbol fonts declared. ...ont{integrals} {LS2}{stixcal} {m} {n}''

How may I get around this?

````
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, enumitem, graphicx, hyperref, latexsym,  babel, blindtext, thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{euro}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$\eqdot$

\end{document}```
````

Comment: As always it is probably a good idea to explicitly cite the exact error message you got.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for the reminder. I did just that.

Comment: Start with removing `latexsym` and `txfonts`. Probably also `stmaryrd`.

Comment: First of drop latexsym, no-one should be using it. And you probably should not attempt to mix so many other fonts with stix which basically provide the same symbols as all of the other symbol packages you're loading

Comment: @egreg I did so, and the error is still with me.

Comment: @Sapiens Oh, and also `amssymb`.

Comment: @daleif May you name one or more packages I use, whose symbols are all included in stix?

Comment: @egreg it is still there.

Comment: @egreg It is gone, after I deleted txfonts and stmaryrd!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no point in loading `txfonts`, because `stix` already provides Times-like fonts.

The `latexsym` package is already covered by `amssymb`, but `stix` covers it anyway. Quite likely, you don't need `stmaryrd` either.

Look at the comments in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{
  amsmath,
%  amssymb, % not needed
  amsthm,
  enumitem,
  graphicx,
%  latexsym, % not needed
%  babel, % why twice?
  blindtext,
  thmtools
}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd} % probably not needed
%\usepackage{txfonts} % surely a cause for the problem
\usepackage{euro}
\usepackage{stix}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\begin{document}

$\eqdot$

test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! For your information, I am able to retain stmaryrd, but now I do not remember why I included it.